# BUSCADOR EN PHP Y MYSQLI

Tags: php, mysql, buscador

estoy haciendo un buscador en PHP y MySQL, ya tengo la pantalla donde muestra los datos y el código. El tema es que no muestra solo ciertos registros, creo que el error esta en el filtro. EJEMPLO: si coloco ICO, solo debería mostrar ICO, pero muestra todos los campos, adjunto códigos
Agradezco su ayuda, me haría de graaan ayuda.

[image: CODIGO PHP]

Pantalla [image: PANTALLA DE VISUALIZACION]

Comment: Por favor, añade el código como texto y no como imagen, pues dificultas a la gente que te pueda ayudar. Muestra el resultado de un echo de la variable $sql, para ver cómo está quedando la consulta montada.

Comment: Si pones "ICO" tu filtro nunca jamás va a filtrar. `strlen("ico") > 3` es falso, con lo cual no entras al if donde añades el condicional a la query.